# ngrx/Data API call with path params

Tags: angular, http, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am trying to implement ngrx Data. However the API does not take query params, instead it takes path/route params. How can I achieve the following calls with ngrx/Data:

- GET /api/v1/Entity/{CategoryIdentifier}  Returns all the entities
- GET/api/v1/Entity/{CategoryIdentifier}/{EntityIdentifier}  Returns
  the entity information based on the uniqueness.
- DELETE
  /api/v1/Entity/{CategoryIdentifier}/{EntityIdentifier}  Deletes the
  entity information.
- POST /api/v1/Entity  Inserts the entity information.
- PUT    /api/v1/Entity  Updates the entity information.

Is there a way to achieve this with ngrxData? Perhaps by modifying the EntityCollectionServiceBase methods?

Comment: Did you check `@ngrx/router-store`, https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store

Comment: You can find some examples for it here https://brianflove.com/2020-06-01/route-params-ngrx-store/

Comment: Would this work with ngrx/data?